# Convert .hdr to NiFti file conversion in python

Tags: python-3.x, hdr, nifti

I'm currently working on a project which handles .nii files from .hdr images.Is there anyway to convert from HDR to NiFti file in python?

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Added tags for the image formats used.